# Python: Scraping Jira

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, jira, python-jira

I have a script which scrapes info from Jira based on the filters I set up in Jira. Currently it just prints the Key, but how do I print the summary and status?

I would like they to appear along side each other.

Thanks!

Here is my code so far:

```
# coding=utf-8

from jira.client import JIRA
options = {'server': 'https://jira.blank.com/'}
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('blank', 'blank'))

for i in jira.search_issues('filter=14270', maxResults=150):
print i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the summary and status simply call those fields as illustrated below:

```
for i in jira.search_issues('filter=14270', maxResults=150):

    issue=i
    print issue.fields.summary
    print issue.fields.status
```

Comment: Thanks. This now prints the summary and status, however it seems to be breaking my loop. It only gives me 1 result even though there should be over a 100.